# pandas append row in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i need to add column and append rows to a dataframe by searching a text file and adding the occurrences

below is my input dataframe 'dfl'

| TextID | Type | Term |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fname | john |
| 1 | lname | doe |
| 2 | fname | jason |
| 3 | loc | 12234 |

```
target_string = []
words = []
s1 = ''
for index, row in dfl.iterrows():
    words = row['Term']
    field_name = row['Type']
    path = "C:\\Users\\myfolder\\"+str(row['chart'])+".txt"
    with open(path,"r") as myfile:
       target_string = myfile.read()
       #here i do the regex
       for match in re.finditer(words, str(target_string),re.IGNORECASE):
           print(match.start(),match.end(),match.group())
           s1 = "match.start()+","+match.end()+","+field_name"
           dfl['Match'] = s1.strip() # this is repeating for every row in dataframe below but i want each row to have its own match field
```

now i want to add the result to the above dataframe 'dfl' in a new column as below

| Text ID | Type | Term | Match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fname | john | 0,4, fname |
| 1 | lname | doe | 8,11,lname |
| 2 | fname | jason | 10,15,fname |
| 3 | loc | 12234 | 20,25,loc |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the 'match' values in a list, and when you are done, create the new column using that list:

```
target_string = []
words = []
match_list = []
s1 = ''
for index, row in dfl.iterrows():
    words = row['Term']
    field_name = row['Type']
    path = "C:\\Users\\myfolder\\"+str(row['chart'])+".txt"
    with open(path,"r") as myfile:
       target_string = myfile.read()
       #here i do the regex
       for match in re.finditer(words, str(target_string),re.IGNORECASE):
           print(match.start(),match.end(),match.group())
           s1 = "match.start()+","+match.end()+","+field_name"
           match_list.append(s1.strip())               

dfl['Match'] = match_list
```

The problem you were having is you were creating the full column in every iteration with the same value (the last value of s1.strip() replacing all the existing values in the column).
If you want to append each individual value to the match column, you should use the index and replace each individual value as: `dfl.loc[idx, 'Match']=s1.strip()`

Comment: used the index value and looks like i have what i need . dfl.loc[index, 'Match']=s1.strip()

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you got it to work as you wanted. In case you have a very large data set, for loops are not optimized for performance, you may want to look into other ways of processing the data (vectorization).